# automatic add "Additional include directory" to user of a static library

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I have an application project (`MyGame`) that uses/calls my static library (`MyLib`) in the same solution:-

```
MySol\
- MyLib (static library)   use "external"
- MyGame (win32 app)       use "MyLib"
```

From the above diagram, `MyLib` need an external library that is not coded by me.
  The external header resides in `D:\external\`.

### Working configuration (tradition)

This is a correct setting that make everything works :-

1. `MyLib`'s **Additional Include Directories** = `D:\external\;`
2. `MyGame`'s **Additional Include Directories** = `D:\MySol\MyLib\;D:\external\;`

Notice that I have to add **Additional Include Directories** = `D:\external\;` into both projects.

It is a mess in real-life when I have a lot of projects.
(tedious, hard-to-maintain, error-prone and dirty)

[Property sheet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/669zx6zc.aspx) can alleviate the problem a little, but not totally cure.

### Dream configuration

I wish I can include shortly as :-

2. `MyGame`'s **Additional Include Directories** = `D:\MySol\MyLib\;`  <-- no "external" yea!

This can't be compiled because the project `MyGame` can't access the header in `\external`.  (non-sense, why is it not automated?)

Adding `MyLib` to `MyGame`'s [**Reference**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez524kew.aspx) (Solution Explorer) doesn't help.

### Question

How to make a user of a static-library project (`MyGame`) automatically *absorb* ***Additional Include Directories*** (`\external`) of the static-library project (`MyLib`)?

### Related question

- [It is possible to do such thing about **linker**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38779944/link-a-program-to-a-static-library-linking-itself-to-another-library/38780447#38780447), but I can't find any setting about **Additional Include Directories**.
- [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830844/creating-a-static-library-visual-studio) is a related question, but it mainly ask "Why", and all solutions suggest that I have to do it manually.  (really?)

Comment: Make a property sheet which adds d:\external to AdditionalIncludeDirectories. Import that property sheet in all projects which need that directory in their search path?

Comment: @stijn Hi, you can post it as a short answer if you wish.  It works. Thank.  My workflow is so smoother because of you.  XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you discovered by now, property sheets are usually the easy way to get things like this partly automated (another way is for instance package managment like [VcPkg](https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg) but that is not (yet) properly established as far as I know, and not as easy as creating a single file and adding it to a project with a couple of clicks).
In this case: create a property sheet which adds d:\external to `AdditionalIncludeDirectories` and import the sheet in all projects needing it. Also if you don't use a pragma for autolinking and/or the libraries are not in a common location known by all projects you can add the library search path and library itself to the linker input in the propperty sheet to get both the compiler and linker happy.